# Java WS-Addressing implementation in SOAP

Tags: java, soap

I'm trying to add WS-Addressing in my SOAP message, but the only way found is by adding nodes directly on the message header.

Does anyone know of a better or cleaner way of implementing this?

best,
Henrik